# Discount Price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I have created a new rule in cart price rule .So i want to know about

`$item->getDiscountCalculationPrice()`  and `$item->getCalculationPrice()` in magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, `$item->getCalculationPrice()` is the item price used for quote calculation process. This method gets the custom price (if it is defined) or original product final price.
Whereas, `$item->getDiscountCalculationPrice()` is the item price after applying the discount, which is then used for quote calculation process.

Comment: Can u explain with example?

Comment: Add any discounted product to the cart and then try to debug the quote item object, the item object will provide you with the clear picture.